# :nth-child not working with list-style:none;

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a playlist. I want the songs to appear in a striped list.

to do that I'm using this css

```
.track-list > ul > li{
  list-style: none;

}    

div ul li:nth-child(even) {
       background-color: #ccc;
    }
```

this is not working at all, but this code below works.

```
  .track-list > ul > li{
  list-style: none;

}
    div ul li:nth-child(even) {
      color: #ccc;
    }
```

But if I remove the `.track-list > ul > li{list-style: none;}` the

```
div ul li:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

is working properly.

here is a screenshot from my browser [image: screenshot]

this puzzles me allot and every advice would be welcome

**Run the snippet full screen to see the issue, the background-color will disappear**

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");


.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
}

.box-item{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
  height: 10vh;
  margin-top: 40px;

}

footer > .listen{
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.playlist-dropdown{
  border: solid 1px #dedede;
}

.interface{
  border-bottom: solid 3px #dedede;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.name-of-song{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.track-list{
   padding-top: 10px;
}

.track-list > ul > li{
  list-style: none;

}

div ul li:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #ccc !important;
}



#play, #pause, #mute, #unmute {
  position: relative;
   display: block;
}

#play {
    position: absolute;

}

#pause:before {
    position: absolute;

}

#pause:after {
    position: absolute;

}



#mute{
    position: absolute;

}

#unmute:before {
    position: absolute;

}

#unmute:after {
    position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>playlist</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>

     <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="box-item ">
           <footer>
             <a class="listen" data-toggle="collapse" href="#playlist-collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
           </footer>
         </div>

        <div id="playlist-collapse" class="playlist-dropdown">
          <div class="interface clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-12 name-of-song">
              Name of track being played
            </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="#" id="play"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a>
              <a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                progress bar
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <a href="#" id="mute"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off"></span></a>
              <a href="#" id="unmute" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                volume-bar
              </div>

          </div> <!--interface ends -->
          <div class="track-list clearfix">
          <ul>
            <li class="track-row">
              <div class="col-md-2 track-number">
                01
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 track-name">
                Track name/ song name
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 track-copyright">
                 &copy;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-duration">
                00:25s
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-number">
                02
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 track-name">
                Track name/ song name 02
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 track-copyright">
                  &copy;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-duration">
                00:25s
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-number">
                03
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 track-name">
                Track name/ song name03
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 track-copyright">
                  &copy;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-duration">
                00:25s
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>


     </div>

   </div><!--container-->

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
$('#play').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('play click clicked');
    //currentPlayingTrack.play();

    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

$('#unmute').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('play click clicked');
    //currentPlayingTrack.play();

    $('#mute').show();
    $('#unmute').hide();
});

$('#mute').on('click', function(event) {
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
    $('#mute').hide();
    $('#unmute').show();
});
</script>
 </div> <!--wrapper -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a code snippet so we can see the HTML structure as well.

Comment: Your `fiddle` works.

Comment: yes I know that is the strange thing

Comment: I added the whole code to the Fiddle, the Fiddle is still working

Comment: Is it maybe a Chrome issue? I haven't tried other browsers yet

Comment: What is your issue? The `list-style` doesn't affect other style.

Comment: well not in the Fiddle, but in Chrome it does.. that is the strange part

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: attach your screen shot.

Comment: Your code snippet works in all browsers.

Comment: Ok I can now see what the "problem" is.... for some reason the `:nth-child` is not working on size bigger than 991px... which is strange because I haven't set any media queries

Comment: not in my computer :(

Comment: Please share the link that you host that web page.

Comment: @AndrewLi run the snippet full screen to see the issue

Comment: Hope my answer will help you.

Comment: so you accepted the answer that is a simple copy of mine without explanation :) I hope you, at least ,read my answer because I gave you the correct explanation and the correct way to solve the issue ... `overflow:hidden` is a hack, you need to correctly use row/container of bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with float. The `li` is getting collpased (`height:0`) because inside you are using `col-*` class without `row`. You need to consider `row` so that float elements (the `col-*`) are correctly cleared then `row` inside `container` to get the correct margin (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");


.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
}

.box-item{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
  height: 10vh;
  margin-top: 40px;

}

footer > .listen{
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.playlist-dropdown{
  border: solid 1px #dedede;
}

.interface{
  border-bottom: solid 3px #dedede;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.name-of-song{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.track-list{
   padding-top: 10px;
}

.track-list > ul > li{
  list-style: none;

}

div ul li:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #ccc !important;
}



#play, #pause, #mute, #unmute {
  position: relative;
   display: block;
}

#play {
    position: absolute;

}

#pause:before {
    position: absolute;

}

#pause:after {
    position: absolute;

}



#mute{
    position: absolute;

}

#unmute:before {
    position: absolute;

}

#unmute:after {
    position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>playlist</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>

     <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="box-item ">
           <footer>
             <a class="listen" data-toggle="collapse" href="#playlist-collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
           </footer>
         </div>

        <div id="playlist-collapse" class="playlist-dropdown">
          <div class="interface clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-12 name-of-song">
              Name of track being played
            </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="#" id="play"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a>
              <a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                progress bar
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <a href="#" id="mute"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off"></span></a>
              <a href="#" id="unmute" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                volume-bar
              </div>

          </div> <!--interface ends -->
          <div class="track-list clearfix">
          <ul class="container-fluid">
            <li class="track-row row">
              <div class="col-md-2 track-number">
                01
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 track-name">
                Track name/ song name
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 track-copyright">
                 &copy;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-duration">
                00:25s
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2 track-number">
                02
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 track-name">
                Track name/ song name 02
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 track-copyright">
                  &copy;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-duration">
                00:25s
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="row">
              <div class="col-md-2 track-number">
                03
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 track-name">
                Track name/ song name03
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 track-copyright">
                  &copy;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-duration">
                00:25s
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>


     </div>

   </div><!--container-->

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
$('#play').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('play click clicked');
    //currentPlayingTrack.play();

    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

$('#unmute').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('play click clicked');
    //currentPlayingTrack.play();

    $('#mute').show();
    $('#unmute').hide();
});

$('#mute').on('click', function(event) {
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
    $('#mute').hide();
    $('#unmute').show();
});
</script>
 </div> <!--wrapper -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Why `list-style` is affecting this?**

When `list-style` is different from `none`, we have the bullets that add a default height to the `li` element even if the element is empty or contains float elements without clearfix. Using `none` will remove this height and we have issues:

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid;
}

span {
  float: left;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>element 3</li>
</ul>

<ul style="list-style:none">
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>element 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><span>float element 1</span></li>
  <li><span>float element 1</span></li>
  <li><span>float element 1</span></li>
</ul>

<ul style="list-style:none">
  <li><span>float element 1</span></li>
  <li><span>float element 1</span></li>
  <li><span>float element 1</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

That issue had caused by the `li` had the `height 0` when the size is bigger than 991px because of **floated div** has `col-*` class.
You use the [`bootstrap`](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) and `col-md-x` has the float property when the screen size is bigger than 991px.
So you have to set the property `overflow:hidden` to `li` to wrap the floated child's content.
Try using like this.

```
.track-list > ul > li{
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

The below code is the fixed one.

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");


.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
}

.box-item{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
  height: 10vh;
  margin-top: 40px;

}

footer > .listen{
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.playlist-dropdown{
  border: solid 1px #dedede;
}

.interface{
  border-bottom: solid 3px #dedede;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
.name-of-song{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.track-list{
   padding-top: 10px;
}

.track-list > ul > li{
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div ul li:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #ccc !important;
}



#play, #pause, #mute, #unmute {
  position: relative;
   display: block;
}

#play {
    position: absolute;

}

#pause:before {
    position: absolute;

}

#pause:after {
    position: absolute;

}



#mute{
    position: absolute;

}

#unmute:before {
    position: absolute;

}

#unmute:after {
    position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>playlist</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>

     <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="box-item ">
           <footer>
             <a class="listen" data-toggle="collapse" href="#playlist-collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
           </footer>
         </div>

        <div id="playlist-collapse" class="playlist-dropdown">
          <div class="interface clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-12 name-of-song">
              Name of track being played
            </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="#" id="play"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a>
              <a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                progress bar
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <a href="#" id="mute"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off"></span></a>
              <a href="#" id="unmute" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                volume-bar
              </div>

          </div> <!--interface ends -->
          <div class="track-list clearfix">
          <ul>
            <li class="track-row">
              <div class="col-md-2 track-number">
                01
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 track-name">
                Track name/ song name
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 track-copyright">
                 &copy;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-duration">
                00:25s
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-number">
                02
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 track-name">
                Track name/ song name 02
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 track-copyright">
                  &copy;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-duration">
                00:25s
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-number">
                03
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 track-name">
                Track name/ song name03
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 track-copyright">
                  &copy;
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 track-duration">
                00:25s
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>


     </div>

   </div><!--container-->

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
$('#play').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('play click clicked');
    //currentPlayingTrack.play();

    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

$('#unmute').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('play click clicked');
    //currentPlayingTrack.play();

    $('#mute').show();
    $('#unmute').hide();
});

$('#mute').on('click', function(event) {
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
    $('#mute').hide();
    $('#unmute').show();
});
</script>
 </div> <!--wrapper -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```